# How to batch save .rdat files?

Tags: r, function, save

I have a pre-written code that produces a data frame with approximately 15000 observations over 50 variables.  Each time I (manually) run this code, it produces different element values in the data frame, which is my objective.  However, I would like to run a few hundred replications of this, and have each individual replication saved as an .rdat file to a pre-specified directory.

At the end of my code, I have

```
df <- as.data.frame(element1, element2, etc.)
save(df, file = "/location/file001.rdat")
```

I would like to have the name of the file increase by one each time it replicates, so I would have a directory of files with file001.rdat, file002.rdat, file003.rdat, etc.  Is this possible to run in R?

Comment: Can't you simply use a for loop and use `paste` with the counter to create the file name?

Comment: Molx, Thanks!  Worked exactly as I needed.